# How to upload mp4 video using wyswing editor in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, wysiwyg

I have added wyswing editor in my custom module. From there, I want to allow to upload mp4 video from that editor.

How can I do that?

Any one please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You should override the Storage type using the `di.xml`. Here is example for `PDF`. Then upload a new type of media should be possible via storage.

```
<type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
                <item name="pdf" xsi:type="string">application/pdf</item>
            </item>
            <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">image/jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">image/jpeg</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">image/png</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">image/gif</item>
                <item name="pdf" xsi:type="string">application/pdf</item>
            </item>
            <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="flv" xsi:type="string">video/x-flv</item>
                <item name="avi" xsi:type="string">video/x-msvideo</item>
                <item name="mov" xsi:type="string">video/x-sgi-movie</item>
                <item name="rm" xsi:type="string">application/vnd.rn-realmedia</item>
                <item name="wmv" xsi:type="string">video/x-ms-wmv</item>
                <item name="pdf" xsi:type="string">application/pdf</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: can you please provide me example of mp4?

Comment: Replace application/pdf with video/mp4

Comment: It's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Although I haven't done it with the video files, I have done some changes to wysiwyg in a project. Maybe I could guide you to the right direction.

Something to know as of `Magento 2.3.x` versions the TinyMCE have been upgraded to v4.

First of all you need to extend the TinyMCE, which you can find documentation [here](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/ui_comp_guide/components/wysiwyg/configure-tinymce-editor.html)

In the plugin for `Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Gallery\DefaultConfigProvider` in the function `afterGetConfig` you can include your custom configuration, which you can get from TinyMCE documentation. Here is the link for the [media config](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs-4x/plugins/media/).

Comment: can you please upload example with code?