# Magento 2 How to upload mp4 and gifs in wysiwyg

Tags: magento2.3, cms, file-upload, upload

Hi I am trying to upload MP4 or GIFS in wysiwyg. But when I try to upload it I am getting the following error:
For MP4 "We don't recognize or support this file extension type."
For GIFS "A technical problem with the server created an error. Try again to continue what you were doing. If the problem persists, try again later."

I looked at the following links but I wasn't getting anywhere if anyone knows please can I get some tips or advice?

Links I have used:
https://github.com/davidroberto/-NOT-MAINTAINED-magento2-enable-mp4-pdf
[How to upload mp4 video using wyswing editor in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/334742/how-to-upload-mp4-video-using-wyswing-editor-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

Some servers have a maximum file size limit for uploads. Check the maximum file size limit on your server and ensure that your file size is within that limit.